# Basic results and meta results in org-mode babel

Tags: org-babel

I'm looking at [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/print_002delements_002dof_002dlist.html) and trying to get the output in babel

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
(defun print-elements-of-list (list)
  "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own."
  (while list
    (print (car list))
    (setq list (cdr list))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: print-elements-of-list

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq animals '(gazelle giraffe lion tiger))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| gazelle | giraffe | lion | tiger |

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results vector 
(print-elements-of-list animals)
#+end_src
```

But there's no output -- except with `:results output`. I'm not sure why I can't get the output in say, `:results list`.

Also, I can do this

```
#+NAME: f
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp 
'(1 2 3)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: f
| 1 | 2 | 3 |


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var c=f()
c
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

But I haven't figured out this meta trick using Prolog output

```
#+name: allchildren1
#+HEADER: :session *prolog-sess*
#+HEADER: :goal list_children1(P,L)
#+begin_src prolog :exports both :results list
list_children(P,L) :- findall(Child, child(Child, P), L).
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: allchildren1
- Correct to: "list_children(P
  L)"? L = [john
  john
  jane
  jane
  sue
  sue
  pete
  hank].
```

Now I try the same trick as the simple elisp above

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var achild=allchildren1() :results output
achild
#+end_src
```

But I get no output. I would like the list `L`'s contents, BTW. Something is happening, though, because in the Prolog session REPL when I evaluate the elisp block it does run the query `list_children(P,L) :- findall(Child, child(Child, P), L).` and displays the answer in the REPL, but, again, not in the org-mode buffer as results. Any ideas about the mysteries of org-mode babel output I should know here? Obviously I need to get into the output and parse out the answer, but how?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: You can say `:results output list`. See [Results of evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) in the Org mode manual. The` collection` option can be either `value` or `output` and its default value is language-dependent; the default is `value` for `elisp`, so if you have print-like functions, you have to specify output explicitly (otherwise you get whatever the print-like function returns - in the above case, you get `nil` because that's what `while` returns).

Comment: Is there some ur/proto- org babel variable that houses the actual raw babel results to a C-c C-c evaluation? If so then we might "take a look under the hood" and not do this endless guess-and-test.

Comment: I don't know of one. What do you mean by "guess-and-test" though? I tend to explicitly specify `:results output` or `:results value`, depending on what I want (and not depending on what the default for the language is supposed to be): that works very nicely.

Comment: Nobody seems to come forward here. Anyway, I guess I'd like to be able to "get into" a named and evaluated code block. I'm expecting after evaluation for the `allchildren1()` block to have something I could then use in another block.